# Is it a good idea to use try/catch to set a Boolean variable?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have a simple case, is my try catch is useful in this case ? I mean is a try/catch can be used for setting a Boolean to `false`?

```
foreach (string file in filePaths) {
    bool err = false;
    BitmapImage img = null;
    try {
        img = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(file));
    } catch {
        err = true;
    }
    if(!err) {
        listPhotos.Add(new PhotoElement(img));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it?  Sure - but you have absolutely no idea _why_ there's an error- that's usually more importing than knowing _if_ there is an error.  So in that case, no, I wouldn't say it's particularly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can certainly do it like that. However, this code could be improved in two ways:

- Move the code for adding the image to the list into `try`. There is no reason to keep it outside `try`/`catch`
- Add some reporting or other way to handle the error. For example, add some placeholder image to the list, for example

[image: Image not found]

It is also a good idea to separate expected errors from unexpected ones. Your `catch` catches all errors, which may mask problems in your code.

```
foreach (string file in filePaths) {
    try {
        listPhotos.Add(new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(file)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        log.Warning("File not found: {0}", fnf);
        listPhotos.Add(ImageNotFoundBitmap);
    }
}
```